# jQuery which to detect empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out when a key press is an empty space, so I did the following:

```
 if (e.which == ' '){

 }
```

however this does not work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`event.which` returns the code of the character pressed. <kbd>space</kbd> key code is `32`, so use it instead:

```
if (e.which === 32) {
    //
}
```

Another way is to convert character to char code with `.charCodeAt()`:

```
if (e.which === " ".charCodeAt(0)) {
    //
}
```

**CHECK:** http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: +1, but just curious, why `===` in this scenario and not just `==`? Not having a go, just wondering.

Comment: === avoid some parsing test

Comment: @mattytommo It is just a good practice to use `===` everywhere in JS, except the cases where you meaningly assume implicit type casting.

Answer (score 4):

Write a test code and alert what the keyCode is.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) { 
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.keyCode || e.which); 
};
```

Learn to debug and you would not be asking these simple questions.

jQuery would have been

```
$(document).keypress( 
    function (e) { 
        console.log(e.which); 
    }
);
```

Comment: If he was debugging in IE though, that'd actually throw an error as `console.log` doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you're looking for: (Assuming you use the keydown event.)

```
if(e.keyCode == '32') {
    // Your code
}
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DeHFL/